# How to Change Bootloader settings for hardware

Tags: linux, bootloader, sd-card, mmc

i'm working on a board that using u-boot

this board has a jumper to toggle between booting from QSPI flash memory or nand

i'm building its image using LDK provided from the vendor based on yocto project

bootloader files are stored on its QSPI Flash memory and I burn kernel image, dtb ,and rootfs on an SD Card and from u-boot I can set some environment variables to load the image

the problem is : for some reason I need to put the bootloader files on the sd card and make the board boot from it

is there a way to do that from u-boot like setting a pointer to point to a second stage of bootloader ? or it is complicated ?

If no can I find a way from inside the image to edit the environment variables of the bootloader in qspi flash?

Comment: Whether you can boot from something other than *"QSPI flash memory or nand"* depends on the SoC, and how the board is configured.  Without more details, this is unanswerable.   BTW you're inconsistent with terminology.  *" I need to put the bootloader files on the sd card and make the board boot from the **mmc**"* -- SD card and MMC are two different standards.  If you mean "boot from SD card", then write "SD card" instead of *"mmc"*.    *"I **burn** kernel image, dtb ,and rootfs on an SD Card"* -- There is no chemical reaction when writing to SD card or any flash.

Comment: You are write, I'm still learning at this topics and still don't know the full details and differences between block devices :